# HTML Responsive Top Navigation Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, responsive

So, I am having trouble trying to create a **Responsive Top Navigation Menu.** I was able to get the hamburger menu bar to show, but the javascript for when the user clicks on the icon is not working.

[image]

Here is what my HTML, CSS, and JavaScript looks like currently at the moment. I am following w3schools.com so that I can create my own website.

**HTML**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
 background-color: #8585e0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 color: #f2f2f2;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
 background-color: #ddd;
 color: black;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
 background-color: #00e68a;
 color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
 display: none;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
 .topnav a.icon {
   float: right;
   display: block;
 }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
 .topnav.responsive a.icon {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
 }
 .topnav.responsive a {
   float: none;
   display: block;
   text-align: left;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Cannon Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="javascript" href="script/javascript.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
      <a href="accomplishments.html">Accomplishments</a>
      <a href="hobbies.html">Hobbies</a>
      <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </div>

      <div style="padding-left:16px">
        <h2>Welcome to my website</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

It be great if you could tell me what is wrong with the onclick feature in javascript and css and see how I can get the hamburger menu icon to actually be able to open and close.

Comment: Icon is not visible at start, how is that supposed to be working?

Comment: @Zlytherin The hamburger icon is showing. I want the icon to be able to pop up like how it is shown here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav this is what I'm trying to do

Comment: @Zlytherin I'm trying to make the icon do the drop down menu so that you can see the navigation menu when in desktop mode, you can see all of the menus, but when it is in tablet or smartphone mode, you press on the three line icon menu to expand the drop down menu. That is my end goal here.

Comment: your code should be working fine. and you have to close your anchor tag

Comment: @KANAYOAUSTINKANE Okay so how is it that when I run the index.html from my folder which is currently located in my desktop right now. I can view the webpage just fine in all modes desktop, tablet, and smartphone. I hit F12 and go to smartphone mode. I cannot click on the hamburger icon, but when I Run code snippet here on stackoverflow and view it in full page and run through the same steps as mentioned previously, the F12 method, and the hamburger icon seems to open. So why is it not opening when I'm in dev mode from my desktop. I like to actually have it OPEN! This is weird!

Comment: @Azazel, I don't really know why. but i guess maybe another element is above your menu bar and because it background is transparent you won't notice it. you can add this to your anchor css style and see if it helps **z-index:10;**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem. You're using `<link>` to a `javascript` file, instead use `<script>` and place of it at the bottom of your `html` file and it should work properly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Cannon Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
      <a href="accomplishments.html">Accomplishments</a>
      <a href="hobbies.html">Hobbies</a>
      <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </div>

      <div style="padding-left:16px">
        <h2>Welcome to my website</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>

    <!-- here -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Haha! Thanks man! It works! I almost went to cut and paste fromy my javascript.js the entire script to the bottom of my HTML but, instead, I just copied script link to the js file and that seems to do the trick! I refreshed the page and did the F12 method in iPhone mode, and the hamburger icon now works! You the bomb! You sir deserve a cookie.

Comment: No problem dude :)

Comment: this is one of those annoying things I just hate in general no matter what kind of coding you do. There is always that sneaking little bastard that won't work and is just one frickin line of codes that solves the problem!

Comment: Yeah, it happens. We just need to keep on learning the quirks and one day they start to make sense. Happy coding!